# static hand gesture recognition using surf descriptor + flann matcher

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to implement static hand gesture recognition for only 6 gestures. Because the hand could turn a bit i tried surf + flann as these are invariant. 
The images are binary and when i compare them i get bad results and i even don't understand them. For example, for images equal i get 1 or 2 good keypoints and for diferent images i get 5 or 6 good keypoints.

Do you have any sugestion to implement gesture recognition for this case?

Result of a train and query image:

[image]

```
double max_dist = 0, min_dist = 100; 

matcher.match(gestoDescriptors,t1descriptors,matches);

for (int i=0; i<gestoDescriptors.rows; i++){
  double dist =  matches[i].distance;
  if (dist<min_dist)
    min_dist = dist;
  if (dist>max_dist)
    max_dist=dist;
}

vector<DMatch>t1_good_matches;
for (int i=0; i<gestoDescriptors.rows; i++){
  if (matches[i].distance<=max(2*min_dist,0.02)){
    t1_good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
  }
}

//-- Draw only "good" matches
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(gestoImage,gestoKeypoints,train1,t1keypoints,t1_good_matches,
img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
           vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

Comment: take a look at [shape_example.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/shape_example.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SURF for feature extraction extensively, but from what I can gather, it's important that the image be reasonably "expressive" in the sense that there are various interest points with unique properties.  I think the main issue you have is that images of hands (and particularly images that have been thresholded to yield binary images) don't have many unique points of interest.  Especially due to the scale and rotation-invariant nature of SURF features, there is very little in your image that would qualify as unique to a specific gesture.

You might want to try using your binary image as a mask just to remove the background, and then try the SURF and FLANN logic on the full-color (or maybe grayscale) hand gestures.

In the long run, I think you'd be better off researching Convolutional Neural Networks if you're serious about building a high-quality gesture recognition system.  CNNs require far less pre-processing of the image and are particularly well-suited for this kind of application.